# With redux form how can I normalize and allow only positive integers on an input type number?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, redux-form

I am on 8.3.7 version of redux-form, I am using the Field which should be allowed to accept ONLY positive integers between the range 0-9999.

```js
const REGEX_SPECIAL_CHARACTERS = /[@\-\_\!\#\$\%\.\&]/;

<Field
    mandatory
    step={1}
    name="fieldName"
    type="number"
    min={0}
    max={9999}
    normalize={(value) => {
        console.log({value});
        return value?.split(REGEX_SPECIAL_CHARACTERS, 1).join('');
    }}
>
    Text
</Field>
```

I am using the `normalize` prop to validate this. If I enter `1.9`, on blur it will set `1` which is ok. If I do `-0` or `-1` or just `-n` (n = any number) it just removes the entire value leaving an empty field and I need it to be ALWAYS `0` if there is whatever value going less than `0`.

I do not know if maybe using the `format` prop but IDK how to use it => https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/docs/api/field.md/#-code-format-value-name-gt-formattedvalue-code-optional-

So any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: You can use onkeyup and preventDefault to restrict - character

Comment: @Abhinav can you provide a code sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this would immediately remove any characters that are not digits, thus only allowing positive integers:

```
const onlyDigits = new RegExp('\\d+');
const parsePositiveInt = (value) => {
    const matches = value.match(onlyDigits);
    return matches ? parseInt(matches[0]) : 0;
};

// ...

normalize={(value) => parsePositiveInt(value).toString()}
```

It's not converting `1.9` to `1` as you described, it would rather turn this into `19`.